# Can all tags have the role attribute?

Tags: html, attributes

I've seen example usage of *role* attributes such as

```
<nav role="navigation">
    ... 
</nav>
```

Can all tags have the *role* attribute, or are they limited to certain specific tags?

I am not looking for what the *role* attribute does. I am interested in *where* it can be used.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=html+role+attribute

Comment: @SLaks Can you point out which page specified exactly what tags can have the role attributes please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. From the HTML5 spec:

> [3.2.7.1 ARIA Role Attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#aria-role-attribute)
>
> Every HTML element may have an ARIA role attribute specified. ...